# LED blinking using Timer without delay function

Tags: c, avr, led

I am writing a simple program that has to blink LEDs with frequency 1Hz using Timer0 and Timer1 without using delay() function.

The program gets complicated, but it doesn't blink. What can I do to make it work?

Below are additional details:
Michrochip studio
F_CPU 16000000UL
Timer0 set on 256.
Timer 1 starts counting from 3036.
The LED is connected to the PB1 PIN.\

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void initTimer0() {
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02);
    TIMSK |= (1 << TOIE0);
}

void initTimer1() {
    TCNT1 = 3036;
    TIMSK |= (1 << TOIE1);
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
    PORTB ^= (1 << DDRB);
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
    TCNT1 = 3036;
}

int main(void) {
    //DDRB |= (1 << DDB1);

    initTimer0();
    initTimer1();

    sei();

    while (1) {
        if (TCNT1 >= 65536) {
            DDB1 = ~DDB1;
            TCNT1 = 3036;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are too many resource about timer and LED on the net to answer this question. Read for eample this: https://www.instructables.com/AVR-Microcontroller-LEDs-Flasher-Using-Timer-Timer/

Comment: Two timers and a while loop to just blink a LED??? It should be possible to do with a single timer interrupt (and empty `while(1)` loop).

Comment: CTC mode is more efficient for arbitrary delay. For 16 MHz CPU clock and 8-bit timer you can configure prescaler to 1024 and get 15625 Hz timer clock. Using OCRxA=124 in CTC mode you'll get 125 Hz interrupt. So using software divider then you can get any interval with granularity of 8 ms.

Comment: `PORTB ^= (1 << DDRB)` is a nonsence. `DDB1 = ~DDB1` is a noncence too. How it ever compiled? Assuming this is a sort of 8-bit Atmega, TCNT1 is a 16-bit register, it cannot be `>= 65536`. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Another approach rather than looking at register values is simply to have the ISR routines toggle the LEDs. (you generally do not want to do any lengthy processing in interrupt functions, but toggling a value is fine. If additional processing is needed, it is better to set a flag and then check and process the flag in your `while(1)` loop in `main()`.)